# Tile Creation Fails even though Application is in Foreground

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to create a tile from a page in the app and it works fine.

```
ShellTile.Create(new Uri(uri, UriKind.Relative), tileData, true);
```

If I'm tombstoning the app and then putting the app back to the foreground and then trying to create the tile, I get this error message:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Tiles can only be created when the application is in the foreground
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.SafeNativeMethods.ThrowExceptionFromHResult(Int32 hr, Exception defaultException)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile.Create(Uri navigationUri, ShellTileData initialData, Boolean supportsWideTile)
```

It only happens with a rather low-end device

Any idea how this can be fixed?

**edit**:
this is the function that calls the tile creation one.

```
    private void OnPinToStartButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyRouteTileHelper.FindCommuteTile() == null)
        {
            LiveTileHelper.CreateEmptyTile();
        }
    }
```

and xaml:

```
   <Button x:Name="PinToStartButton" Click="OnPinToStartButtonClicked" />
```

Comment: Where are you trying to create the tile? Is it in a navigation related event or in direct response to a user action?

Comment: button click (so it's definitely foreground)

Comment: In that case have you got a way to reproduce the issue?

Comment: In the answer you mention tombstoning. You also mention creating the tile through a button click. Are you trying to create the tile within the application event handlers? Can you provide the method event of which page the tile creation is in?

Comment: @MattLacey yeah, low end device, tombstone and then click on the button that creates the tile

Comment: @ShawnKendrot added the answer to you question in my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, before you can create the tile just check whether the app is already created or not. If it is already created then you will get an error. I think may the error is masked in your case.

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(()=>{
ShellTile TileToFind = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("any string of uri or search for unique prop"));
if (TileToFind == null)
{
   ShellTile.Create(Navi_Uri , tileData, true);
   MessageBox.Show("Tile is created.");
}
else
{
   TileToFind.Update(tileData);
   MessageBox.Show("Tile is updated");
}});
```

**EDIT**
I think invalid operation occurs when the code executes on a seperate thread. You have to make it on the UI thread. Check for the part of code that i edited.

Anyways get back if you didnt get the answer.

Comment: Hey @max, thanks for your help. I'm already checking if the tile exists. See the edit answer for the missing calling function